# Dynamically allocationg 2D vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-allocation

I seem to get lost when I tried to dynamically create 2d vector of (boost)bitsets.

My code:

```
class Configuration
{
    vector< vector<dynamic_bitset<> > > configset;
    Configuration(unsigned groups, unsigned players, unsigned weeks){
        //allocation on heap, this works
        vector< vector<dynamic_bitset<> > > configset(weeks, vector<dynamic_bitset<> >(groups, dynamic_bitset<>(players)));

        //this does not work, how to create this dynamically, with new?
        configset = new vector< vector<dynamic_bitset<> > > (weeks, new vector<dynamic_bitset<> >(groups, new dynamic_bitset<>(players)));
    }
};
```

How to initialize attribute **configset** with **new** operator? Thanks.

Comment: `configset` is not a pointer so would should not be using `new`.

Comment: also not related but make your constructor public.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes :D. Just switched to C++ project after few years ehh.

Comment: You don't need any `new` here.

Comment: @user2174310 I would stay away from `new` in C++.  There are still places you need it but most of the time if you are using `new` you are doing something the hard way.

Comment: There's almost never any reason to dynamically allocate standard containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is configset is allocated as part of your `Configuration` class. It will resize internally to fit what you want but it will be destroyed when Configuration is destroyed. Should work just fine unless you really need a pointer. If this works for you just replace the allocation with calls to `resize` to make it any shape you need (like this: `configset.resize(weeks, vector<dynamic_bitset>(groups, dynamic_bitset(players)))`). This should work just fine in most situations.

If you want to allocate it explicitly you need to store a pointer. Define configset like this:

```
vector< vector<dynamic_bitset<> > > *configset;
```

And most of your code will work. Make sure you delete it in the destructor.

An even better approach is to use a unique_ptr (or some other smart pointer) like this:

```
unique_ptr<vector<vector<dynamic_bitset<>>>> configset;

....
configset.reset(new vector....);
```

This way it is dynamically allocated, and you can treat it as a pointer but you won't forget to delete it.

You'll need to apply this to the internal structures as well if you need them to be dynamically allocated all the way through. That is

```
vector<vector<dynamic_bitset<>*>*>* configset;
or
unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<dynamic_bitset<>>>>>> configset;
```

Finally your allocation only creates one `dynamic_bitset<>` and one `vector<dynamic_bitset<>>` and copies the pointer to all locations. This is probably not what you want. Either drop the pointers (this is not java) or  have a loop to initialize it properly.